# API repeated calls using React Redux Hooks Saga?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-hooks, saga

I integrated redux hooks saga with API, I want to load the projects once and listen for changes, the API keeps getting called with:

```
import { loadProjects } from '../../store/actions';

useEffect(() => {
    props.loadProjects();
}, []);


return (<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>)

const mapStatetoProps = state => state.Projects;

export default connect( mapStatetoProps, { loadProjects })(InvoicesList);
```

this is causing infinity loop, load data from API -> update store -> renders for changes -> load data again -> ...

What is the solution to for loading projects once, do I call before rendering or in reducer initial state? or is this a normal thing while using hooks.

```
export const loadProjects = () => ({
    type: PROJECTS_LIST,
    payload: {}
});
```

this fragment is inside index.js -> App.js -> project.js

```
import store from './store';

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

this is the App.js code

```
return (
                <React.Fragment>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                    

                        {userRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
                            <Authmiddleware
                                path={route.path}
                                layout={Layout}
                                component={route.component}
                                key={idx}
                            />
                        ))}

                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </React.Fragment>
        
          );
        }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        layout: state.Layout
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

Comment: Can we see the reducer with the case « PROJECTS_LIST » ?

Comment: If the `useEffect` has an empty dependency this means it is triggered only once when the component mounts. If this is being called over and over again then this means the component is being unmounted and mounted again. What is rendering this component? (along with the reducer code previously requested)

Comment: you need use mapDispatchToProps for redux actions